# unable to display correct image in viewpager after reload staggered gridview

Tags: android, arrays, android-viewpager, slide

I am developing an image gallery application for Android. The images needed to be displayed in staggered gridview. Once I click on one of the images in staggered gridview, i am able to view images in full screen using viewpager. Images are able to slide left and right. The current problem that I am facing is, after reload new pictures in staggered gridview, I am unable to display the new array of images.Your help is needed, 
Thank you!
Below is the code to reload pages

```
private void loadMoreData() {

    if ( isLoading )
        return;

    mListFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isLoading = true;
    flickerGetImagesRequest();
}
```

after reload, will call flickerGetImagesRequest() method here

```
{

    String url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest";
    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
    builder.appendQueryParameter("api_key", "5e045abd4baba4bbcd866e1864ca9d7b");
    //builder.appendQueryParameter("method", "flickr.interestingness.getList"); //TBS
    builder.appendQueryParameter("method", "flickr.photos.search");
    builder.appendQueryParameter("tags","klcc,husky");
    //builder.appendQueryParameter("sort","relevance");
    builder.appendQueryParameter("format", "json");
    builder.appendQueryParameter("nojsoncallback", "1");
    builder.appendQueryParameter("per_page", "10");
    builder.appendQueryParameter("page", Integer.toString(currPage));

    gsonObjRequest = new GsonRequest<FlickrResponsePhotos>(Request.Method.GET, builder.toString(),
            FlickrResponsePhotos.class, null, new Response.Listener<FlickrResponsePhotos>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(FlickrResponsePhotos response) {
            try { 
                if(response != null) {
                    //mStaggeredView.onRefreshComplete();
                    parseFlickrImageResponse(response);
                    currPage++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("JSON parse error");
            }
            stopProgress();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
            // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user credentials.
            // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on client side when sending api request.
            // In this case you can check how client is forming the api and debug accordingly.
            // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle accordingly.
            if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ClientError) { 
            } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
            } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
            } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            }
            //mStaggeredView.onRefreshComplete();
            stopProgress();
            showToast(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    gsonObjRequest.setTag(TAG_REQUEST); 
    mVolleyQueue.add(gsonObjRequest);
}
```

Below is the code for images to display in staggered gridview after refresh.

```
private void parseFlickrImageResponse(FlickrResponsePhotos response) {

        FlickrGetImagesResponse photos = response.getPhotos(); //pass array of images to Picture Activity
        String[] photoUrl;

        photoUrl = new String[photos.getPhotos().size()]; //all elements are null
        for (int index = 0; index < photos.getPhotos().size(); index++) {

            FlickrImage flkrImage = photos.getPhotos().get(index);
            photoUrl[index]=flkrImage.getImageUrl();
            StaggeredGridViewItem item = null;
            item = new FlickrGridItem1(this, flkrImage, photoUrl); //pass one image of index
            mStaggeredView.addItem(item);
        }
```

Below is the code to display images in viewpager once onclick

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View photoRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image, container,
                false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) photoRow.findViewById(R.id.img_flickr);
        image.setImageBitmap(imageFromUrl(imageArrayList[position]));

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(photoRow);
        return photoRow;
    }
```

imageArrayList[position] always display the last position of array. 
Let say i want to display array size [10] images in staggeredgridview. I am able to slide to first 10 images correctly in viewpager. However, after I have reload the pages, it only able to display the new 10 images, now able to display the images in previous pages.

Let me know if the problem is not clear enough..Thank you!!

Comment: not clear of your problem, more code please.

Comment: @zdd , I have updated more code. Basically, the problem is that, the viewpager not able to display photos of previous page+current page.It can only display the next 10 photos

Comment: where is the code of `reload` ?

Comment: @zdd, I have pasted the reload code above :)